# EmberJS - Lazy loading inside a template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I lazy load relationship inside the template?

```
// models/folder.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  children: DS.hasMany('item', { inverse: 'parent', async: true })
});

// models/item.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  parent: DS.belongsTo('folder', { inverse: 'children', async: true })
});
```

At this point the folder is loaded (`except of his children)` and the children were never loaded.

I would like to make EmberJS load the children of a folder when I run `{{folder.children}}` inside a template.

Comment: It should be loaded. `{{folder.children.length}}`

Comment: No it does not load. Look at this example: https://emberjs.jsbin.com/cofiqikoho/1/edit?html,js,console,output EmberJS is not trying to load `items`.

Comment: In jsbin you provide, there is no child payload data. Push some payload for children, then you can see

Comment: I want to load the children only if I need them. I my app I have a list of parents and the children are displayed only when the user expands a parent. I though there is a way to load calling `{{folder.children}}` I guess I will implement a computed `{{folder.reloadedChildren}}`.

Comment: No need to to like that. Access the child properties when is needed. ED loads them.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your children section of ui in `if` helper. Then if the condition is true, your children promise, fullfilled.

```
<button {{action (mut showChildren) true}}>Expand</button>

{{#if showChildren}}
  {{#each parent.children as |child|}}
    <span>{{child.name}}</span>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: @Charles I updated your [jsbin](https://emberjs.jsbin.com/radufetowu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I don't want to load the children with the parent list.

Comment: @Charles They are not loaded with parent. If you access any attribute of the children then they loaded. These attributes are like `length` or even iterating over the children

Comment: @Charles I showed you in [this jsbin](https://emberjs.jsbin.com/ficaquf/1/edit?html,js,console,output) that the children would be loaded when needed (accessing to them)

Comment: Informations about children are still loaded with parent: `relationships: {
          items: {
            data: [{type: 'item', id:2}]
          }
        }` . It's just the Id but if there are a lot of children it can be too much data.